# Match Duplicate Words in HTML Text Using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, match, cpu-word

I have jquery script that matches duplicate words within an HTML text.  The problem is if the text I want to match is in HTML form it has to be embedded in the coding script itself.  I've tried both transferring text to be matched into the script and also substituting the HTML text with textarea text.  Neither method seems to help.  I also tried converting a few strings to javascript, but still no budge.  I think the problem is I could be missing something in how I have my getelementid string coded.   Here's what I've done so far:

```
    var textarea = document.getElementById('p').value;
    words = textarea.split(' '),
    sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateWords = [],
    sentences = textarea.split('.'),
    sortedSentences = sentences.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateSentences = [];


for (var i=0; i<sortedWords.length-1; i++) {
    if (sortedWords[i+1] == sortedWords[i]) {
        duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
    }
}
duplicateWords = $.unique(duplicateWords);



$('input.words').click(function(){
    var highlighted = $.map(words, function(word){
        if ($.inArray(word, duplicateWords) > -1)
            return '<<<<' + word + '>>>>';
        else return word;
    });

    document.getElementById('p').value = highlighted.join(' ');
    return false;
});
```

So to be clear:  With text inside a textarea this jquery/javascript works. Like this:

```
<input type="button" class="words" value="Find duplicate words">
|


<textarea id="p" cols="30" rows="30">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ut enim ad minim veniam. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea>
```

But like this it does not:

```
<input type="button" class="words" value="Find duplicate words">
|


<textarea id="p" cols="30" rows="30"></textarea>
```

How do I remedy this so that I can pass any text into either an innerHTML or textarea for this match function to be accessible?

Comment: The reason this works when text is in the html is because you are getting the value of `textarea` as soon as the page loads. If you want this to work dynamically, you'll have to get the value of `p` within the `onclick` function

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the problem with the way this code is written is that you are referencing the value of your variables as they are when they are declared (when the page loads) and not as they would be when you want your function to execute. To fix this, change their scope to the click function and re-calculate their values every time the button is clicked. I have demonstrated an example just by moving all of your code into the `.click` function.

```js
$('input.words').click(function() {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('p').value;
  words = textarea.split(' '),
    sortedWords = words.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateWords = [],
    sentences = textarea.split('.'),
    sortedSentences = sentences.slice(0).sort(),
    duplicateSentences = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < sortedWords.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sortedWords[i + 1] == sortedWords[i]) {
      duplicateWords.push(sortedWords[i]);
    }
  }
  duplicateWords = $.unique(duplicateWords);

  var highlighted = $.map(words, function(word) {
    if ($.inArray(word, duplicateWords) > -1)
      return '<<<<' + word + '>>>>';
    else return word;
  });

  document.getElementById('p').value = highlighted.join(' ');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="words" value="Find duplicate words"> |
<textarea id="p"></textarea>
```